# Is relative boundary of the epigraph the same as relative interior of the domain of a convex function?

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Let $f \colon \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be convex.

From what I understand, a subdifferential
$$
\partial f(x) :=\{z:f(x)\,\,\ge\,\,f(x')+ \langle z, x-x' \rangle \ \forall x' \in \text{dom}(f) \}
$$
of $f$ at $x$ is guaranteed to be non-empty when $x$ is in the relative interior of the domain of $f$, $\text{dom}(f)$.

I can understand that the subdifferential at $x$ is guaranteed to be nonempty when $x$ **is on the relative boundary of the epigraph of $f$**.
But, I **do not** understand how it is possible for us to guarantee that  the subdifferential will be non-empty on the relative interior.

Are both of these statements true?

1. *the subdifferential is always nonempty on the relative interior of the domain.*
2. *the subdifferential is always nonempty for the points $x \in \mathbb{R^n}$ for which $(x,f(x))$ is a point on the relative boundary of the epigraph.*

Comment: Why isn't the answer accepted?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes - see Rockafellar's *Convex Analysis*.

2) No. Consider $f(x)=-\sqrt{x}$ if $x\geq 0$ and $+\infty$ if $x<0$. Then $(0,0)$ is in the (relative) boundary of the epigraph but $\partial f(0)=\varnothing$.